# Ut syllabās gravēs verbōrum didicimus?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, reference-request

Hanc rēgulam didicī dē verbīs:

- Sī syllaba paenultima brevis est, syllaba antepaenultima gravis fit.
- Sī autem longa est, ipsa gravis fit.

Ut hanc rēgulam didicimus? Ex grammaticīs? Quō tempore haec rēgula vēra est? Ita loquuntur Caesar et Cicerō et aliī ōrātōrēs id tempore?